# Android: getting IllegalAccessError only on built APKs

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

So I'm getting this error only when I'm running the APK and app crashes immediately. (no matter signed, unsigned release mode or debug)

but when I run the app from android studio, everything's fine.
I have both kotlin and java files in the project.

and the error is caused by a kotlin file by the way.
any idea ?

here's the error log:

```
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com.app.myapp.fragment.HomeFragment$onViewCreated$1
                                                                                at com.app.myapp.fragment.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.kt:155)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1430)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3140)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2687)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1932)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7530)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMess
```

and here's the onViewCreated method:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        adapter = MyAdapter(list)
        adapter!!.addOnItemClickListener { pos , Data->
            ...

        }
}
```

there's an interface in recyclerView's adapter which passes data on each item Click. once again, this code works on debug mode and I used this structure a lot in other java classes.

any help would be appreciated. This thing is driving me crazy !

Comment: paste your error log

Comment: @SushinPv updated the question.

Comment: Could you post us here also the HomeFragment code please ? Around line 155

Comment: Post the method `HomeFragment#onViewCreated()`

Comment: @m0skit0 updated. thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Traabefi updated. thanks in advanced.

Comment: Which is line 155?